# Angular HttpClient streaming get request or have back-end trigger a request?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I've developed restful http services with Node to communicate with my angular front-end.

In the back-end I'm using the MSSQL npm package which is an extension of TEDIOUS npm package made by microsoft to communicate with MS SQL Server.

In that package I'm using the 'stream' function to listen for changes.

I'd want to **trigger a get request on the Angular 6 front end** from the backend when that happens, but after looking through the documentation I can't find anything that would facilitate this strategy.

Comment: It's not really possible to call into your front end from your back end using HTTP. Instead, maybe look at using something like SignalR to communicate using sockets

Comment: sounds like you need to use web sockets

Comment: Ah, you guys are right. I'll look into that, thanks! @user184994 if you want to post it as an answer I'll mark it as the right one, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't by definition -- must use websockets for two-way communication.

Ended up implementing Socket.IO which has excellent documentation, tutorials and examples.